# Term for creating a fantasy word from all letters of two existing words?

Tags: compounds, creative-writing

If I have two words - let's say "lamp" and "vampire" and I put all of their letters together to form a new fantasy word. e.g. "vapamlimper" does this process have a name?

I already considered terms like [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau) or [blend word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_word) but they don't quite hit the spot.

This is also not a pure [neologism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologism) as there is an additional rule to it (must be all letters of two existing words).

Comment: Neologism: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/it/dizionario/inglese/neologism

Comment: It's a neologism with a twist though because it is restricted to the letters of two existing words, maybe there is something more specific?

Comment: This is a special type of anagram.  I don't know if there's a common name for this kind of anagram. If not, I'd coin "multi-word anagram."

Comment: The thing is though that an anagram creates already existing words from other existing words and this one is creating a new word from two existing words so maybe a  ... New-O-Duogram :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [National Puzzlers' League](http://www.puzzlers.org) maintains a [guide to wordplay terminology](http://enigma.puzzlers.org/guide/composing) that has a few terms that might be useful. Some of these terms are commonly used, and others were coined by NPL members.

- [transposal](http://enigma.puzzlers.org/guide/arrange#transposal) is any rearrangement of letters from a word or phrase to another word or phrase
- [anagram](http://enigma.puzzlers.org/guide/arrange#anagram), as defined by NPL, is a transposal where one arrangement forms a clue or description of the second arrangement. NPL imposes some additional rules for good anagrams; these are at the link.
- [alternade](http://enigma.puzzlers.org/guide/combine#alternade) would work, if your single word were formed by taking one letter at a time from each of the source words in order, e.g. HAT + ERS = HEARTS.
- [rebade](http://enigma.puzzlers.org/guide/rebi#rebade) is a variation of the alternade that is also a rebus
- [interlock](http://enigma.puzzlers.org/guide/combine#interlock) is like an alternade, except the source words don't have to be the same length
- [transade](http://enigma.puzzlers.org/guide/combine#transade) would work, if your single word were formed by transposing each of your source words separately and then appending them together, e.g. ASH + REV = SHAVER.
- [alterposal](http://enigma.puzzlers.org/guide/non-guide/ngflats#alterposal) is like an alternade where the source words are transposed first
- [transinterlock](http://enigma.puzzlers.org/guide/non-guide/ngflats#transinterlock) is like an interlock where one of the the source words is transposed first

Given these definitions, the example you have given, LAMP + VAMPIRE = VAPAMLIMPER, is merely a transposal, and since it is a [protologism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protologism) rather than a neologism, I would call it a **transposal protologism** or a **protologistic transposal**.

You could combine your source words using the more restrictive rules for one of the specific transposals to make things more interesting. For example, LAMP + VAMPIRE = VAMLAPIMPRE would be a protologistic interlock. LAMP + VAMPIRE = VAMMAPPIREL would be a protologistic transinterlock.

Comment: No-one but a puzzler is going to recognise those words, but +1 for relevant research.

Answer (score 5):

You can call it a [blend word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_word)

> In linguistics, a blend word or a blend is a word formed from parts of two or more other words. These parts are sometimes, but not always, morphemes.

It's also similar to a [portmanteau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portmanteau), except that with a portmanteau, the beginning is from one word and the end from the other, rather than mixed up.

Comment: Thanks, I know about both of those and thought there might be something more specific?

Comment: @OliverBestwalter If you considered those and rejected them, that should be in the question along with the reasons _why_ you rejected them.

Comment: @Cascabel I hadn't rejected them as such, but I know about them and maybe they are good descriptions, but I am hoping for something more specific. I asked it the way I think is good enough and I am no expert on the topic. I just wanted to ask a simple question :)

Comment: @OliverBestwalter Right now your question shows no basic research, and that is a reason to close hereabouts.

Comment: @Cascabel: better?

Comment: My +1 should answer that comment! @OliverBestwalter